# How to retrieve Entity instance of an EntityType field inside a twig template in Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, many-to-many, entity, formbuilder

I am currently experiencing a problem with recovering the data I need, and I really hope that you will be able to help me. I am trying to create a form via the Symfony formbuilder to create an object that I call `Site`. This object contains users to fill in the form. To do so, I go through the Symfony entitytype to get my users from the database. I recover them well. However, I would like not to just display the name of each user to check but in addition to that to, i would like to display their data like address, telephone number etc in an HTML table with several columns. However I can't get my users objects recovered into my view with all their properties to pass. I can simply enter a label displaying several info that I can not put in a table. For information, users come from a many-to-many relationship. Do you have an idea to get all my users object across the view and not pass only a string to it? Here is my code:

```
 $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('adress')
            ->add('postalCode')
            ->add('city')
            ->add('phoneNumber')
            ->add('observations')
            ->add('country', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Country::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'by_reference' => false
            ])
            ->add('devise', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Devise::class,
                'choice_label' => 'symbol',
            ])
            ->add('timezone', EntityType::class,[
                'class' => TimeZone::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'by_reference' => false
            ])
            ->add('users', EntityType::class ,
                [
                    // looks for choices from this entity
                    'class' => User::class,
                    'choice_label' =>  function (User $user) {
                        return $user->getFirstName() .' ' . $user->getLastName();
                    },
                    'choices' =>  $this->userRepository->getUsersWithRoleBellowUserByCustomer($customer, $creator) ,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false
                ])
            ->add('criterions',EntityType::class ,
                [
                    // looks for choices from this entity
                    'class' => Criterion::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false
                ])
            ->add('tags',EntityType::class ,
                [
                    // looks for choices from this entity
                    'class' => Tag::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false
                ])
```

and I would like something like that in my view :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}



<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Firstname</td>
        <td>Adress</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        {% for userField in form.users %}
            <td>
                userField.name
                userField.firstName
                userField.adress
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Here what i'm receiving when i make a dump of user.vars after making a foreach on form.users

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi9k1.png

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want to display all users in a template? I don't think so. The usual way is to have a selectBox showing all users, the better way is an ajax search box. 
You must always keep in mind that in the beginning your form is almost empty probably exposing default values. The key is using the formEvent for building your form. 
Is this probably what you are looking for?

Comment: You can access your entity instance with form.vars.value. look {{dump(form)}}

Comment: @SamMumm i don't want to display all users. I made a method to filter them. This is working.. The system already made a request to get the label of all users (first name last name) so i wish to find a method to get the full objects stored sometwhere (maybe )  without using an ajax request to redo another request. .

Comment: @threeside I 've altready tryed form.vars.value. I 've made a foreach accross users and tryed to make a form.vars of each user but the only value that i get is an integer that seem to be the id. I can't get all others values of each users object

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bind a Jquery event to your `EntityType` field and create an Ajax request to get information you want.

Something like :

```
$('#form_user_field').on('change', function(){
     var userId = $(this).val()
     $.ajax
         your ajax request
         success:function(user){
             change table content
         }
}
```

Comment: @Juien FOURNIER thank you for your answer. But i need to display all the users informations at the beggining and not only load the datas on checkboxes changes.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to see. Do you want to always see ALL users informations, in this case, just pass a variable to twig containing desired informations with $this->userRepository->getUsersWithRoleBellowUserByCustomer($customer, $creator) plus the form variable.

Comment: Indeed, it is not really clear what you want. Probably a user table with the probabillity to edit, add, show and delete like in typical admin sites? If so, follow the advise of Julian and first get a simple repo request.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `choice_attr` option

```
//...
        ->add('yourfield', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => YourEntity::class,
            'choice_label' => 'the_field_you_want_as_label',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'choice_value' => 'id',
            'choice_attr'  => function (YourEntity $entity) {
                return [
                    'data-foo' => $entity->getBar(),
                ];
            }
        ])
```

Then you can customize your input in a template of yours and deal with your property value